# npm doesn't install tsun or angular-cli correctly

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm

I had a problem a few days ago installing angular-cli where it doesn't work without me creating an alias.

Today I tried installing tsun and it doesn't work either:

```
prompt:javascript $ npm install -g tsun
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/bin/tsun -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/lib/node_modules/tsun/bin/tsun
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/lib
├── tsun@0.3.3 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@>=2.0.0

npm WARN tsun@0.3.3 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.0.0 but none was installed.
prompt:javascript $ tsun
-bash: tsun: command not found
prompt:javascript $ npm install -g typescript
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/bin/tsserver -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/bin/tsc -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.1.0/lib
└── typescript@2.0.10 

prompt:javascript $ tsun
-bash: tsun: command not found
prompt:javascript $ tsc --version
message TS6029: Version 1.7.5
prompt:javascript $
```

What is wrong here with npm?

Comment: Hi, did you try sudo installing? sudo npm install -g tsun

Comment: Which version of Node are you using, and are you using nvm?